# Canyon Ultimate CF SL 7 2022 steerer tube compression plug stuck?

Tags: fork, headset, steerer, carbon-fork, canyon

This is concerning my friend's Ultimate CF SL 7 (105) 2022. Ridden approx 5000 km so far. Everything's been fine, up until a recent ride, but now there was noticeable movement (in the direction of the bike on the road, not laterally) in the headset. The diagnosis was that the fork or headset, or both, had 'come loose', for want of a better term.

We decided to disassemble the headset

- unscrewed the top screw holding the spacers in place
- removed cockpit & spacers
- removed bearing
- unscrewed fork?

Then, we tried to reassemble everything, but it appears that the compression plug has slid down the fork. We are no longer able to attach the top plate onto the steerer tube, as the fixture (compression plug) is about 110 mm into the fork.

[image]

It is now impossible to reassemble the headset. We're planning to take this bike to an LBS asap, but we're keen to have all available information in order to expedite the process of making the bike roadworthy again. Hence, a few questions:

- Any ideas as to how we can retrieve the compression plug to its ideal position?
- If it is irretrievable, can we simply stick a new plug into the fork and it's going to be OK?
- How might this be related to the initial issue - the loose headset?

If you have any insights to add, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance!